# How to reduce frame title box size in a special case

Tags: beamer, height, frame-title

how to reduce frame title box size in this case, a tried  [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254814/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-height-of-the-frame-title-box-in-beamer) but it changes the color of the titlebox

```
 \documentclass{beamer}


    \mode<presentation>

    \useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
    %\useoutertheme{shadow}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usecolortheme{whale}

    \setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

    \mode
    <all>


    \author{diabonas}
    \title{Frame border}
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    {\color{black}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
    }

    \makeatletter
    \mode<presentation>

    \useoutertheme{split}


    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
      color(0pt)=(frametitle.bg);
      color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle right.bg)}

    \AtBeginDocument{
      \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{.982\paperwidth}{%
        color(0pt)=(bg);
        color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
    }

    \addtobeamertemplate{headline}
    {}
    {%
      \vskip-0.2pt
      \hskip0.11cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
      \vskip-2pt
    }


    \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
    {%
      \nointerlineskip%
      \vskip-2pt%
      \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
          \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
              \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
              \leftskip0.3cm%
              \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle\par%
              \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
                {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
              \fi%
              \nointerlineskip
              \vbox{}%
              \end{minipage}}%
          \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
          \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
          \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
            \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
            \pgfusepath{clip}
            \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
          \end{pgfpicture}
          \hskip-\paperwidth%
          \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
      }%
      \nointerlineskip
        \vskip-0.2pt
        \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-0.885cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
        \vskip-2pt
    }



    \mode
    <all>

    \makeatother
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{content}
    frame
    \end{frame}
    \frame{Content}
    \begin{frame}
    content
    \end{frame}
    \section{test}
    \begin{frame}{Content}
    content
    \end{frame}
    \section{test2}
    \end{document}
```

Same MWE is working properly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458515/incomplete-side-rule-in-beamer/458518#458518) but the problem occur when i add this lines :

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
```

[image]

Comment: Are your real frametitles going to be in arabic or latin letters? Should they be left or right aligned?

Comment: Frametitle will be RTL Arabic letters, Right alignd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test the following?

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
%\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\mode
<all>


\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
{\color{black}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
}

\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme{split}


\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(frametitle right.bg);
  color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle.bg)}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{.982\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}
{}
{%
  \vskip-0.2pt
  \hskip\paperwidth\hskip-0.11cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
  \vskip-2pt
}


\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
{%
    \selectlanguage{english}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex% <- was 0.75ex
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.6cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\hfill\otherlanguage{arabic}{\insertframetitle}\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-0.885cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}



\mode
<all>

\makeatother
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\amiri[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{content}
frame
\end{frame}
\frame{Content}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\section{test}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\section{test2}
\end{document}
```

[image]