# RTL table of content on beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, right-to-left, bidi, bullets

I used this answer [related to titlebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458799/how-to-reduce-frame-title-box-size-in-a-special-case) size, but this causes the TOC be centered or justified if i add `\flushright`. This code solve the issue partially but suppress numbering bullets (fig1):

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL {\inserttocsectionnumber}
 \inserttocsection\par
}
```

[image]

How to align this RTL properly (fig2):

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
%\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\mode
<all>

%
\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
{\color{black}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
}

\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>
%
\useoutertheme{split}
%
%
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(frametitle right.bg);
  color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle.bg)}

\AtBeginDocument{
 \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{.982\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
}
%
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}
{}
{%
  \vskip-0.2pt
  \hskip\paperwidth\hskip-0.11cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
  \vskip-2pt
}
%
%
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
{%
    \selectlanguage{english}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
 \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
   \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex% <- was 0.75ex
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.6cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\hfill\otherlanguage{arabic}{\insertframetitle}\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-0.885cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}


\mode
<all>

\makeatother
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

%%This solve the issue partially but suppress bullets
%\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
%\setRTL {\inserttocsectionnumber}
% \inserttocsection\par
%}

\begin{document}
%%============multicolumns TOC ==============
%\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\begin{frame}{Outline}%to allow TOC break
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
       \begin{Arabic}  
       \flushright                                        
            \tableofcontents[sections=5-, subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide,hideothersubsections]%hideothersubsections                 
       \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}
 %  \flushright 
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
       \begin{Arabic}
           \flushright
            \tableofcontents[sections=-4, subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide, hideothersubsections]%hideothersubsections
        \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%============End multicolumns TOC ==============

\frame{Content}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\section{Test o Two}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\section{Test Two}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\section{Test Three}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Your problem is not caused by the answer you link to, this would also happen with the default theme in combination with a RTL language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `\raggedleft` to the `section in toc` template:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\amiri[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{myball}{
\leavevmode\leftskip=2.75ex%
  \llap{%
    \normalsize%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.7ex}{1ex}{1ex}
      \pgftext{\beamer@usesphere{section number projected}{tocsphere}}
      \pgftext{%
        \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
        \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
        \color{fg!90!bg}%
        \inserttocsectionnumber}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \kern1.25ex}%
    \raggedleft \inserttocsection\par
}
[action]
{\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\scriptsize}}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{myball}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=5ex%
  \llap{\raise0.1ex\beamer@usesphere{subsection number projected}{bigsphere}\kern1ex}%
  \raggedleft \inserttocsubsection\par%
}


\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[myball]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%%============multicolumns TOC ==============
%\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\begin{frame}{Outline}%to allow TOC break
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
       \begin{Arabic}             
            \tableofcontents[sections=5-, subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide,hideothersubsections]%hideothersubsections                 
       \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
       \begin{Arabic}
            \tableofcontents[sections=-4, subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide, hideothersubsections]%hideothersubsections
        \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%============End multicolumns TOC ==============

\frame{Content}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\section{Test o Two}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\section{Test Two}
\section{Test one and Test Two test test}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\section{Test Three}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\section{Test one and Test Two}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly,is it possible to add  indentation for subsections in the TOC?

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour Maybe it would be better to have this as a new question