# How to complete these side borders in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, luatex, babel, right-to-left, bidi

There are some great answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458515/incomplete-side-rule-in-beamer)  and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48800/beamer-right-frame-border) about the same issue but different code samples, in this case I am using a new package `beamer-rl`[CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer-rl?lang=en) with last update of Babel package, it solves problems of RTL languages in beamer, but i faced this problem of uncomplete side borders :

```
    % !TeX TS-program = LualaTex

  \documentclass[hyperref=unicode,dvipsnames]{beamer}% compress,
    \usepackage{hologo} % pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex logos 
    \mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}


    %====== side border ====
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        {\color{blue}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}}%    
    }

    \usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
    \babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}
    \babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
    \babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
    \usepackage{beamer-rl}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{here}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    Creating beamer presentation for  right to left language  (like arabic) using \hologo{pdfLaTeX} or \hologo{XeLaTeX} 
    still poses many problems due to bugs not currently resolved especially for colors and hyperlinks 
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One dirty workaround: use exactly version 3.51 of beamer, not newer, not older. This was the one and only version where the shadows supported transparency.

Comment: I will try it, Thank you @samcarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458518/36296 still works without any modifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
%\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\mode
<all>


\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
{\color{black}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
}

\makeatletter
\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme{split}


\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(frametitle.bg);
  color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle right.bg)}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{.982\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}
{}
{%
  \vskip-0.2pt
  \hskip0.11cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
  \vskip-2pt
}


\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-0.885cm\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}



\mode
<all>

\makeatother

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
\usepackage{beamer-rl}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{content}
content
\end{frame}
\frame{Content}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\section{test}
\begin{frame}{Content}
content
\end{frame}
\section{test2}
\end{document}
```

[image]